# How i can determine if the table is null in VB.Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

Here's the problem, i'm trying to determine if the table is empty or not because if it's empty it will process the next transaction.

Code(Transaction)

```
 Public Sub insCust()
    i = dtgOnGoing.CurrentRow.Index

    If dtgOnGoing.Rows(i).Cells.Item(0).Value = Nothing Then
        Try
            c = DataGridViewCustomer.CurrentRow.Index

            dt = New DataTable
            da = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT SUM(jobprice) from custsrv WHERE GROUP BY custName=@custName", sqlCon)
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custName", DataGridViewCustomer.Item(0, c).Value)
            da.Fill(dt)
            sqlCon.Close()

            total = DataGridViewCustomer.Item(2, c).Value

            sqlCon.Open()
            dt = New DataTable
            da = New MySqlDataAdapter("INSERT INTO billing (`custName`, `totalAmt`) VALUES (@custName,@total)", sqlCon)
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custName", DataGridViewCustomer.Item(0, c).Value)
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalAmt", total)
            da.Fill(dt)
            MessageBox.Show("Payment is proceeded", "XYZ Auto Repair Shop", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            sqlCon.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No Transaction, please try again", "XYZ Auto Repair Shop", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If

End Sub
```

The problem is like this: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
If so, how can i determine if its empty or not?

Comment: Have you tried returning a count of records to determine if it's empty or not?

Comment: No, not yet and i used this condition to display items in the datagridview:      i = DataGridViewCustomer.CurrentRow.Index
        connect_DB()
        dt = New DataTable
        da = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT  jobSrv as 'Service', jobPrice as 'Price' " &
                                  "FROM custsrv  WHERE custName=@custName AND jobStats='ON-GOING' ", sqlCon)
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custName", DataGridViewCustomer.Item(0, i).Value)
        da.Fill(dt)
        disconnect_DB()
        dtgOnGoing.DataSource = dt